# Why does my .text() manipulation not work after an AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, join, split

Why my `split` and `join` are not working??

```
$.getJSON(url, function (data) {
    // create ".tags" elements and populate them with data
});
$(".tags").text(function (i, val) {
   return val.split(",").join(", ");
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8TdZ3/1/)

I just simply want to add space after every **','** (comma).

Comment: You are splitting it before getting any result from JSON response.

Comment: Using AJAX is a pretty important detail to leave out of the question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an Ajax call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Comment: @Phil Its not a dup of that linked question. Theres no return value here.

Comment: Thanks @GoodSp33d .. i know its silly one.. :P

Comment: @GoodSp33d The implementation is slightly different but the [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14220323/283366) outlines the problem and solution

Comment: but why down votes  for this question .. x(

Comment: @Era because you left out the most important details

Comment: But that question is totally different from mine.. and Phil if i could have any idea of my mistake then i surely didnt ask this question here. what you say @GoodSp33d

Comment: @Era read the accepted answer on that post (all of it) and you will understand where you went wrong and how you can fix the problem

Comment: @Era Nobody is blaming you for asking a question that's been asked before (in fact, this particular question is asked almost every day); what's important, though, is to write the smallest code to reproduce the issue **in the question itself**.

Comment: But Phill .. before searching for solution, you must know the problem behind this.. and i was not aware about the issue..

Comment: No.. I am not talking about blaming .. i m just worried about down votes.. :(

Comment: @Era getting marked as a duplicate isn't a bad thing. It just reduces clutter on StackOverflow

Comment: Anyways.. Thanks all for your valuable time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As `$.getJSON` is async call, you need to perform your operation in callback method of `$.getJSON`

```
$.getJSON('http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bXClHuexaq?indent=2', function (data) {
  //... your code

    $(".tags").text(function (i, val) {
        return val.split(",").join(", ");
    });
 });
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8TdZ3/2/)

Answer (score 3):

As Satpal had mentioned using $.getJSON  is required

```
$.getJSON(url, function (data) {
    // code
    $(".tags").text(function (i, val) {
        return val.split(",").join(", ");
    });
 });
```

However, as a general practice I'd recommend to use regular expression instead, mainly because for longer strings arrays need more memory

```
$(".tags").text(function(i, val) {
    return val.replace(/,/g, ", ");
});
```

Comment: @Darren That's a little harsh. OP didn't include all the relevant information in their post

Comment: @Darren What do you mean by L2R..?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy [**Learn 2(to) Read**](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=l2r)

Answer (score 0):

Place your split logic in callback.Check out the following jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/8TdZ3/6/

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $.getJSON('http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bXClHuexaq?indent=2', function (data) {
        var output = "<table width='100%' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>";
        output += "<tr>";

        output += "<th width='20%'>" + 'Tags' + "</th>";
        output += "<th width='15%'>" + 'Friends' + "</th>";
        output += "</tr>";
        for (var i in data) {
            output += "<tr>";

            output += "<td class='tags'>" + data[i].tags + "</td>";
            output += "<td>";
            for (var j = 0; j < data[i].friends.length; j++) {
                output += "<div>" + data[i].friends[j].name + "</div>";
            }
            output += "</td>";
            output += "</tr>";
        }
        output += "</table>";

        document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML = output;
          $(".tags").text(function (i, val) {
        alert(i);
        return val.split(",").join("#");
    });

    });

});
```